# Prevent SSH attacks

Tags: ssh, iptables, brute-force-attacks

I'm trying to setup iptables rules to only allow 3 attempts by an IP per minute to connect to the servir via SSH, and drop all the connections after to prevent SSH attacks; but it seems i'm doing something wrong!

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --rsource
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 3 --name DEFAULT --rsource -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you better have to use `fail2ban`, because your ipfilter rules also block legitimate connections. `fail2ban` will only block IPs after failed connections.

Next, a common practice is to ban IPs when they try to connect to port 22, and bind your ssh server to another port. You then face only a couple illegitimate connection per week if your computer is not a well known target.

For the precise question you asked :

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 -j DROP
```

Comment: Since the server is a low end vps, I'm trying to keep resource consumption to the minimum while maintaining it as secure as possible. I've already changed the ssh server port. Should I keep those rules (above) to the new port and ban the default one (22)?

Comment: Fail2ban is in fact the best solution, even for low VPS

Answer (score 8):

You can implement what you want with the following 2 rules

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 3 -j DROP
```

Note that using `-A`which adds rules to the  end of the chain can fall foul of the way that iptables rules are processed i.e. in order so if there is a general DROP or an allow rule before yours is reached than they will never be acted on.

Having said that you may also find [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a better way of implementing this kind of block.

Comment: When i try to add those rules, i get an error message: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Comment: Upvote for fail2ban.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try the LIMIT module.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m limit --limit 3/minute -j ACCEPT
```